# Flex 3: Progress bar with transparent track

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, progress-bar, skinning

I want to implement a progress bar where the track should be transparent, and with a border around. I believe I can only do this with an advanced programmatic skin, am I correct? How can I implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think that? Have you tried using the skin templates in [Fireworks](http://www.developria.com/2009/10/easy-flex-skinning-with-firewo.html) and setting the track skin to be transparent?

I think you can also write a progress bar completely from scratch as long as you understand the events it is listening for, but I don't have the dtails handy and I was answering this while waiting for FB to launch, so that's all the time I have.